# Why my edit mode is bigger than my object

Tags: objects, export, add-on, edit-mode, vertices

I created a rock by rock generator addon, but when i go to edit mode, the vertices are much bigger than my rock, then i can't export to glb because my object gets deformed.

Please helpp, i'm completely new at blender.

[image: my rock in edit mode]

[image: out of edit mode]

Comment: hello, maybe show the modifiers, maybe you have a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: It's that? https://imgur.com/8IWX5Ga
Sorry, I dont know much yet

Comment: yes it looks like you have 2 Subdivision Surface modifiers (with a very high level of subdivision, not sure it's useful), so it virtually changes the shape of your object, as if it had much more faces, and it rounds it

Comment: what do I do to change that? Delete one or modify some configuration? If I change to "simple" the rock fits exactly to the shape of edit mode

Comment: duplicate your object in order to keep a copy somewhere, only keep one Subdivision Surface modifier, lower down its level of subdivision, apply the modifier, and see what it gives?

Comment: i got it!!! thanksssss, you helped a lot

Comment: Consider checking the "Apply Modifiers" under "Geometry" in the exporter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate your object in order to keep a copy somewhere, only keep one *Subdivision Surface* modifier, lower down its level of subdivision, apply the modifier, and see what it gives until you're satisfied. Keep your object as low-poly as possible.